# Error during sp_refreshsqlmodule after altering table type

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to add a column to a user-defined table type.
I have done some research and here is what I have now:

```
  -- First, rename existing table type to something else
EXEC sp_rename 'TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE', 'TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE_1'

-- Create the new table type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE] AS TABLE(
    [MY_FIELD] [varchar](20) NULL        
)
GO

-- Do a refresh of the SP/views so that the SP/views will refer to the new table type
-- Save the list of dependencies to a temporary table
SELECT  'sp_refreshsqlmodule ' + quotename('MySchemaName.' +object_name(referencing_id), '''') AS SQL_CMD
INTO    #TEMPSQL
FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE   referenced_class_desc = 'TYPE' and referenced_entity_name =  'TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
-- Do a loop for the list of dependencies, use dynamic SQL to execute the SQL commands
DECLARE c_Cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  SQL_CMD
    FROM    #TEMPSQL

OPEN c_Cur
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cur INTO @sql
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @statement = @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_Cur INTO @sql
END

CLOSE c_Cur
DEALLOCATE c_Cur

-- Drop the old table type
DROP TYPE TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE_1

DROP TABLE #TEMPSQL
```

Unfortunately, while refreshing stored/procedures (their dependencies) to reflect the new type I am getting the following error:

> Procedure sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal, Line 85 [Batch Start Line 0]
>
> Operand type clash: TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE is incompatible with
>   TT_MY_TABLE_TYPE_1.

I expect that the error is something else since all I did was adding one column to the new type.

When I try to alter the function that has this type as a dependency, I have the same Operand type clash error

Could you help me identify, what is the root cause of this problem?

Comment: You can't `ALTER` custom data types that are referenced by objects. If you are changing it's definition, you'll need to either `DROP` the objects that use it, `ALTER` it, and the recreate the other objects, or create a new you, `ALTER` the objects that reference the old ones to reference the new type, and then you can `DROP` the old one (and rename the new one). This is when things like source control come very useful.

Comment: I was following this topic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196482/how-to-do-alter-table-type-efficiently?newreg=8541661f8c114a3a819159e3a35fa954

Answer (score 1):

To anyone, that may come across this problem:
The issue was  nested dependencies.
You need to run **sp_refreshsqlmodule** starting from the bottom of the dependency hierarchy. If you try to refresh the Stored Procedure, that uses this table type and passes it further, you will get this operand type clash error